# copy with memcpy structs double pointer member content to another struct

Tags: c

I want to use C to copy all content i from struct member indexs to struct A with memcpy. I don't know how to do that. Can you please show me how it done if even possible?

Let say we have 3 defined struct's:

```
struct A {
    int destination[100];
};

struct B
{
  int i;
};


struct C {
    struct B ** indexs;
};
```

The idea is to get from **struct C** all member **indexs** and copy from **indexs** all the content of **i** to **struct A**:

```
struct A  a;

struct C * tasks = calloc(2,  sizeof(struct C));

tasks[0].indexs = (struct B **)calloc((size_t)5, sizeof(struct B *));
tasks[0].indexs[0] = malloc(sizeof (int));
tasks[0].indexs[1] = malloc(sizeof (int));
tasks[0].indexs[2] = malloc(sizeof (int));
tasks[0].indexs[3] = malloc(sizeof (int));

tasks[0].indexs[0]->i =1;
tasks[0].indexs[1]->i =2;
tasks[0].indexs[2]->i =3;
tasks[0].indexs[3]->i =4;

memcpy(&a.destination, &tasks[0].indexs[0]->i, 100 * sizeof (int));

printf("Hello World: %i ", a.destination[1]);
```

Comment: First, try to compile the code yourself and remove the compiler errors.

Comment: After removing the compile error, look at `calloc(struct B)`: you allocate an array of `struct B`s, but assign it to an array of *pointers to struct B*.

Comment: The expression `calloc(100, sizeof(struct B))` will allocate memory for `100` elements of type `struct B`. It returns a pointer to the first element. That pointer will have the type `struct B *`. It's a dynamic allocation of an array of `B` structures, similar to `struct B array[100];`. Why do you then use `struct B **` for the returned pointer? That would only make sense if you created an array of *pointers* to `struct B` (like `struct B *array[100];`). Or a dynamic "2D" jagged array of `struct B` objects.

Comment: You may want to visualize the memory layout. Draw a picture of (array of) structs and how they are connected via pointer arrows.

Comment: The potential for [trailing padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119123/2505965) in `struct B` makes this a dubious approach, even if the alignment of each structure happens to work out in this particular example (i.e., `sizeof (struct B) == sizeof (int)`). Best to write your own copying function(s) (after fixing the type issues).

Comment: I have removed all compile error... but still no luck with memcpy.. it print 0 instead of 2

Comment: indexs => indexes

Comment: @i486 this don't solve anything it just naming

Comment: `tasks[0].indexs[0] = malloc(sizeof (int));`? But `tasks[i].indexs[j]` is supposed to be a `B` object, not an `int`. There's no guarantee that the size of `B` is equal to the size of `int` (see [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)).

Comment: Also, why do you need an array of *pointers*? What is the problem that is supposed to solve? Why can't you have an array of `B` structure objects? Like `struct B *indexs;`

Comment: @dsfddgdggd It is a comment, not answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `memcpy`

```
memcpy(&a.destination, &tasks[0].indexs[0]->i, 100 * sizeof (int));
```

is just plain wrong.

`&tasks[0].indexs[0]->i` is a pointer to a single `int` value, it's not an array, it's not a pointer, it's a single plain `int` value.

Because `&tasks[0].indexs[0]->i` is a pointer to a single `int` value, and not the first element of an array, the `memcpy` call will go well out of bounds of that single value. And going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

You can't copy a set of single distinct values into an array using `memcpy`, you need to use an explicit loop to copy them one by one:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    a.destination[i] = tasks[0].indexs[i]->i;
}
```

---

Also note that the `memcpy` call is wrong for another reason as well: `&a.destination` is a pointer to the array itself, with a type of `int (*)[100]`.

What is expected is a pointer to the first element of the array which would be `&a.destination[0]` (or just plain `a.destination` which will *decay* to the correct pointer type).

Comment: i'm using double pointers, becouse NULL can be used only with pointers and struct B *indexs; will result in copy of other pointer - thank you for the solution that is also the only way i could think of